# Problems with Vector.Reflect in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I am working on a 2D top down project in Unity2D. Hoping to familiarize myself with the Unity physics engine I decided to give the player object physics based movement by applying force to the character. One of the features I was hoping to implement into this movement was a ricochet effect where they player will bounce off of walls on collision.

Currently my script uses Vector2.Reflect to calculate this:

```
private Rigidbody2D playerRB;

    public float playerSpeed = 0.01f;
    public float playerBounce = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Fetch components from object.
        playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Process player input
        Vector3 playerInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0);
        playerRB.AddForce(playerInput * playerSpeed);

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision Detected");

        Vector2 bounceDirection = Vector2.Reflect(playerRB.velocity.normalized, collision.contacts[0].normal).normalized;
        playerRB.AddForce(bounceDirection * playerBounce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    }
```

Unfortunately, my current script is not producing the desired result. When I collide with the wall, nothing happens, the player object doesn't seem to recieve any opposing forces. I suspect the issue could be related to the player object being a square and potentially having multiple collision points against a flat surface. Is there a better way for me to implement this? Would raycasting be a better solution?

Comment: Does the collision happen?  Are you seeing your log in the console?

Comment: Yes the collisions are detected, only one log for each collision as well so that may mean there's only one collision point.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the force, maybe its just not enough oomph.   try something crazy like 10,000.  At least then you can rule out some things.

Comment: I have also tried that didn't seem like any number I used made a difference. I even tried negative values to see if there was any change but it just doesn't seem to be applying force to the object. I thought it may be possible that the forward force was greater than the opposing bounce force but the value I tried was 123123 and didn't see any change.

Comment: Try debugging the normal and relected values using Debug.DrawLine from Update/Fixed update.  Store the normal and reflection in class variables and DrawLine for each of those values.  Might shed some light on the situation.

Comment: I managed to get much closer to the intended result by adding a 2D physics material to my boundaries to produce the bounce. However, now when the player collides with the wall they are vibrating against it. Is it possible that the physics is not being calculated fast enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the collision has already occurred.
Caching the velocity in FixedUpdate fixes the issue.

```
private Vector2 velocity;

void Start()
{
    playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 playerInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0);
    playerRB.AddForce(playerInput * playerSpeed);

    velocity = playerRB.velocity;
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    reflection = Vector2.Reflect(velocity, collision.contacts[0].normal);
    playerRB.AddForce(reflection * playerBounce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly the result I was looking for. It is similar to what I was able to come up with but the removal of the velocity method seems to solve the problem. Is the heading calculation required because we are no longer using the velocity method? Just wondering because I originally chose the velocity because I thought it would remove the need to calculate heading. p.s. sorry not enough reputation to upvote :)

Comment: Ok so i figured out the root of the issue.  Since the collision has already occurred the velocity has been changed.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Does this provide the same movement as your previous answer?

Comment: To me it feels more accurate and removes the need for one extra variable.  Had to reduce the reflection force a bit (makes sense since it was using delta position before), that was the major difference i noticed.